# How to pass a serializableExtra from different android applications?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, serializable

I'm trying to send a SerializableExtra from an application to another one.
I use

```java
resultIntent.putExtra("thing", fc);
```

and in the receive application :

```java
Thing theThing = (Thing) data.getSerializableExtra("thing");
```

But since the applications doesn't have the same names I got the following error:

```
Java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered ClassNotFoundException reading a Serializable object (name = com.test.senderapp.Thing)
```

And I can't modify the sender application , I need to find a way to make it works only controlling the application that receive the intent.

Thank you

Comment: Can you show the code for `Thing.java` What datatypes does `Thing` use? I would recommend you only pass primitive types between apps tbh

Comment: it contains only String array and Arraylist<Integer>, I know it's not well done but I can't modify the sender app

Answer (score 0):

Use Content Providers to achieve this.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.

We were discussing this issue into something pretty similar; we wanted that a keyboard could share data with another app and use it with a combination of other features.

The goal is that you define which data to expose and other apps can use that similar to what the Contact's app does; which you can access a CursorLoader to fetch all of the user's contacts.

On the other hand, as a second solution, you can make your second app receive a String and send the object as a JSON; but I'd rather prefer the first one if you're going to keep adding more objects or summing up other applications.

Comment: I can't modify the app that send the object